# How do roots absorb oxygen in hyrdroculture/hydroponics?

Tags: hydroponic

I was told soil needs good aeration to allow oxygen to enter the roots. If the soil is waterlogged, the plant will drown due to oxygen deprivation. Is this true and how is it possible for hydroponics?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have airation I believe like those ones in fish tanks? Also you will need to have constant water moving around for best results with pumps and such.